# Loop through business rule checks on stream while only reading stream once C#

Tags: c#, optimization, stream, biztalk, pipeline

I'm overthinking this probably.

I have a stream of data, which contains a delimited string. I have a ton of business rules defined in a DB that basically say "if the value in this position equals [this] then this rule is true" - it's a lot more complicated as the rules can be grouped/negated (if not this then true). So on so forth.

Anyways...current state i read the stream into a string, loop through business rule groups iterating the string each time, and compile an arraylist of the business rules this string matched up to. Not efficient at all given this is a streaming component and for each new group of rules it adds to processing time.

My requirement is to now deter from instantiating a string, read through the stream one time and still come up with the same result (array list of business rules ID that apply)

Is this possible? Not looking for code, just concept. Have a few ideas but they don't even sound good on paper.

Comment: Iterating through the string is the absolute least expensive operation you've mentioned, and making all the rules some share the same iteration is not practical. The requirement is insane. Here's what you need to do: Call your superior who dreamed up this face-eatingly delusional notion, and say, "I have a very particular set of skills..."

Comment: It would probably be easier to offer suggestions or "don't do this" with some code. Is the requirement to improve the performance of this process, and if yes, how much of an improvement are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: The same question for every kind of performance improvement: Have you actually profiled this? And did the results seriously suggest that this was the best way to start improving? The amount of pointless work being done because people don't profile before optimising is always astonishing to me.

Comment: Current solution is iterating string per business rule. So, OK, suppose that is the best option as list of business rules grow, and they will grow exponentially, then so will the latency between delivery and decisions. That being said - i came up with a more object oriented approach that may suffice. Creating objects for these business rules and caching a list of these objects, i'll define a nullable property for "actual value". Making a deep copy as each document arrives, then 'read once' updating each obj with actual value for that document; returning rule listwhere expected val = actual val

Comment: Is this a BizTalk question?

Comment: Meh sort've. After I realized I was unable to achieve a 100% streaming pipeline component given the result of these business rules would be promoted to context i focused on just the concept of optimizing the rule evaluation in a normal pipeline component. Anyways - since people were curious i did a benchmark on both solutions. Average execution time of iteration method is about 1200ms while object oriented streaming model is 12ms - happy to share if anyone is interested